# Prove $D_\mu\phi^\dagger=(D_\mu\phi)^\dagger$ [Question closed, the statement was not true]

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, differentiation, covariance

In gauge transformation, $D_\mu$ was defined to be $\partial_\mu-igA_\mu$.
However, I have hard time to see that $D_\mu\phi^\dagger=(D_\mu\phi)^\dagger$ without ambiguity.
(A comparable example in QED might be found here [Why define $D_\mu = \partial_\mu -ieA_\mu$ with the electric charge $e$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498230/))

Could you prove $D_\mu\phi^\dagger=(D_\mu\phi)^\dagger$ in a formal setting/mathematically?

Comment: $(D_\mu\phi)^\dagger=\phi^{\dagger}{D_\mu}^{\dagger}.$ And in QED, it's $\phi^{\dagger}(i\gamma^{\mu}D_\mu -m )\phi$.

Comment: Cinaed Simson, but knowing the defined $D_\mu = \partial_\mu -igA_\mu$ shouldn't $D_\mu \phi^\dagger$ be expanded as:

$$ \phi^\dagger (\partial_\mu -igA_\mu^\dagger)$$

Or does the field $A_mu$ not have a complex conjugate and simply stays the same?

Does $\partial_\mu$ have a complex conjugate?

Comment: So you think $(2x_\mu)^\dagger$ is a differential operator simply because it can be written $(\partial_\mu x^2)^\dagger$?

Comment: Am I missing something or is the OP asking for the proof of a statement that’s clearly untrue?

Comment: @AfterShave It was untrue. You were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the covariant derivative depends on what it is acting. If the object is the field of an electron, then, as we well know, the electric charge is $-e$ the covariant derivative $\textit{applied}$ to the field ([with the signature $(+,-,-,...,-)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative)) is
$$ D_\mu\phi= \partial_\mu\phi-iqA_\mu\phi =\partial_\mu\phi+ieA_\mu\phi.$$
In general, if the field you are considering has electric charge $Qe$, with $Q$ a real number, then
$$ D_\mu\phi=\partial_\mu\phi+iQeA_\mu\phi.$$
With the real coordinate system and $Q\neq 0$,
$$ (D_\mu\phi)^\dagger=\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger-iQeA_\mu\phi^\dagger 
\neq 
D_\mu\phi^\dagger =\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger+iQeA_\mu\phi^\dagger .$$
The point is: the explicit expression for the covariant derivative with respect to a symmetry depends on the representation of the field it is acting on. The representations of the electromagnetic symmetry group, $U(1)$, are classified by a real number, aka the electric charge. The term with the vector field in the covariant derivative must have the appropriate charge, otherwise it would not transform as a covariant derivative under a gauge transformation.

Now to your question. The field $\phi$ has, say, charge $Qe$, with $Q$ a number. The complex conjugate of the field has opposite charge, namely $-Qe$. Considering what I say above, the covariant derivative for $\phi^\dagger$ must go with $-Qe$ and not with $Qe$.